# XML android file root element not visible

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

Hello everybody I am new to Android. I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1eN40zcKB4)

But I can't find the same window shown at the second 7.58.

If I go on `"Add">>"XML Android File`" I can only see a windows of XML `android file/layout` but in the root element display nothing is shown. I have `android 4.2`.

Comment: you want to add an XML file in layout folder right?

Comment: yes but when I try the root element is empty so it is different from the one of the video. Also the graphics is different because of the different version of android studio

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to couple of reasons . you might have missed some required property. due to which it shows only xml window but whole view is not visible (but will warn you as well).

or

Sometimes it may be case when some view is dynamically used as in case of your tutorial . in which `ListView` will get its values in run time so you won't see any `View` in xml file , You can use emulator or Your phone to check if the view appears on runtime.

Try running the project . Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it. I wrote an xml layout file without choosing the root element and that's it. I wrote the same things of the tutorial inside the xml file and it worked!